# Copy text to clipboard now that execCommand("copy") is obsolete

Tags: javascript

I just saw on the Mozilla page that execCommand() is obsolete https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

*"This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any time. Try to avoid using it."*

This is what I currently use to copy text to the user's clipboard when the user clicks a "copy text" button. Is there another way to do it?

```
 var input = // input element with the text
 input.focus();
 input.setSelectionRange(0,99999);
 document.execCommand("copy");
 input.blur();
```

Edit: This [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) does not answer the question. It suggests the same obsolete solution.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: The alternative is the [Clipboard API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API), as stated on MDN: "This API is designed to supersede accessing the clipboard using `document.execCommand()`." However note that support for this API is not widespread yet, so as recommended in the linked dupe target, you'll probably end up falling back to `document.execCommand("copy");` anyway for wider browser coverage.

Comment: Thanks. Sounds like they made the solution obsolete without having the replacement ready.

Comment: @user984003 Deprecating a feature that does not yet have a replacement? In MY browser? It's more likely than you think!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

From Klaycon's comment to the question. The replacement is the Clipboard API.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard_API

```
// In this example, the text to copy would be in an element with id = textcopy

var text_to_copy = document.getElementById("textcopy").innerHTML;

if (!navigator.clipboard){
    // use old commandExec() way
} else{
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text_to_copy).then(
        function(){
            alert("yeah!"); // success 
        })
      .catch(
         function() {
            alert("err"); // error
      });
} 

// Some browsers require that copy be initiated by a user action.
// You can, for example, put the code inside a button listener.
```

I tested this (Feb 2020) in (Windows) Chrome, Firefox, new Edge, Opera, iOS Safari, iOS Chrome, iOS app webview. Clipboard writeText works great.

Comment: Don't forget to check if the user gave permissions for this: `navigator.permissions.query({ name: 'clipboard-read' })`

Comment: Permission is necessary to read from the clipboard and to write, but not to writeText. (Not sure what is the difference between write and writeText.)

Comment: @user984003 The Clipboard interface's writeText() property writes the specified text string to the system clipboard.
The Clipboard method write() writes arbitrary data, such as images, to the clipboard. This can be used to implement cut and copy functionality.

Comment: And also don't forget that not all browsers have access to `navigator.permissions` as of December 2021, including Safari. https://caniuse.com/?search=navigator.permissions

Comment: At 08/Feb, its not compatible only with Internet Explorer  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Clipboard/writeText

Comment: @Emanuel Makes perfect sense. Nobody should be supporting IE anymore

Comment: Note the security comment: `Secure context: This feature is available only in secure contexts (HTTPS), in some or all supporting browsers.` Among other things, this makes it difficult test on a local development environment if you’re not using HTTPS, such as when using XAMPP.